# Getting a class name from a property reference

Tags: php

I was wondering if you could get the class name and property name from a property reference in PHP?

```
class Test {
    public static $TestProp;
}
GetDoc(& Test::$TestProp);
function GetDoc($prop) {
    $className = getClassName($prop);
    $propertyName = getPropertyName($prop);
}
```

what I'm looking for is if it is possible to create the functions getClassName and getPropertyName?

Comment: Just wondering; what's the reason you want to find that out?

Comment: I'm trying to create a method that I can create html controls by just passing in the property, passing in the class and property name is too clunky IMO.

Comment: I found a way to get the class name, working on a way to get the property name, when I figure that out I'll post my answer.

Comment: yeah never mind looks like what I want to do is impossible, would be nice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the way to get this to work there is a lot of magic that goes on just to get this to work, but in my case it's worth it.

```
class Test {
    private $props = array();
    function __get($name) {
       return new Property(get_called_class(), $name, $this->props[$name]);
    }
    function __set($name, $value) {
       $props[$name] = $value;
    }
}
class Property {
    public $name;
    public $class;
    public $value;
    function __construct($class, $name, $value) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    function __toString() {
        return $value.'';
    }
}
function GetClassByProperty($prop) {
    return $prop->class.'->'.$prop->name;
}
$t = new Test();
$t->Name = "Test";
echo GetClassByProperty($t->Name);
```

this example yes I know it's complex, but it does the job how I'd want it to, will print out "Test->Name"  I can also get the value by saying $prop->value.  If I want to compare the value to another object I can simply do this:

```
if($t->Name == "Test") { echo "It worked!!"; }
```

hope this isn't too confusing but it was a fun exploration into PHP.

Comment: now what's not great about this solution is if you want to set the value to another variable you have to remember to say "$t->Name->value"

Comment: It just really seems you're doing it wrong here, but without a deeper understanding of why it should work this way, I'm afraid my answer can't be more helpful either :)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking to get in the result, just didn't think it would take all of this to get working.  Making a method to create a control for each property and I only wanted to pass in the property reference, not really the same thing, but hey it works and now the syntax is simple.

Comment: here's a link to what I was able to complete with the above answer if you're interested: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/New-Frameworks-PHP-Databases-Thoughts-42140.S.244283657?view=&gid=42140&type=member&item=244283657

Answer (score 2):

What you want is basically not possible; a property doesn't know its parent structure.

The only sane thing I could think of is to use reflection for it:

```
class Test
{
    public static $TestProp = '123';
}

//GetDoc(& Test::$TestProp);
GetDoc('Test', 'TestProp');

function GetDoc($className, $propName)
{
    $rc = new ReflectionClass($className);

    $propValue = $rc->getStaticPropertyValue($propName);
}
```

Within the `Test` class you could use `__CLASS__` as a convenient reference for the class name.

Answer (score -1):

Php have a build in function called get_class

Comment: That requires an object to be passed, not a static property of a class.

Comment: What if I first call "clone" to the input object then use get_class, is it workable?

Comment: I only want to pass in a reference of a property and get the class name and property name, this can be done in other languages, just wondering if it can be done with PHP.